# Cannot call getEnumerator() on associative array coming from a JSON in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
   Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -UseWebLogin
    $json = Get-PnPFile -Url $FolderRelativeURL -AsString
    Write-host $json.files
    $object = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
    $object.items | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-host $_.folder 
        $object.files.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Key) - $($_.Value)"}

        #$item = Get-PnPFile -Url "$($FolderRelativeURLGeneral) $($_.folder)" -AsString
    }

}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

I am trying to loop through the variables inside the files key of the following json:

```
{
   "files":{
      "item":"item.html",
      "header":"header.html",
      "content":"content.html",
   },
   "items":[
      {
         "folder":"Advert",
         "file":"ad2.json"
      },
      {
         "folder":"YouTube",
         "file":"ad3.json"
      },
    ]
}
```

However, the GetEnumerator() method isn't working on the property files of the object. Is there a way to make it work? Strangely enough it works for object.items.

I get the following error while running the script:

```
Error: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'GetEnumerator'.
```

Comment: You can refer to item, header, content, if they're always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message implies, [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances ([`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject)) by default - and that type doesn't have an enumerator.<sup>[1]</sup>

In *PowerShell [Core] 6+* you can use the `-AsHashtable` switch, which returns `[hashtable]` instance that *do* have a `.GetEnumerator()` method.

In *Windows PowerShell*, you must enumerate the properties differently, via the (hidden) `.psobject.Properties` collection (also work in PowerShell [Core]):

```
$fromJson = @'
{
   "files":{
      "item":"item.html",
      "header":"header.html",
      "content":"content.html",
   },
   "items":[
      {
         "folder":"Advert",
         "file":"ad2.json"
      },
      {
         "folder":"YouTube",
         "file":"ad3.json"
      },
    ]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$fromJson.Files.psobject.Properties | foreach {
  "$($_.Name) - $($_.Value)"
}
```

Note the need to use `.Name` instead of `.Key`; however, if you are dealing with hashtables, note that `.Name` works too.

The above yields:

```
item - item.html
header - header.html
content - content.html
```

---

<sup>It works on property `.Items`, because it contains an *array* (`[object[]`), and arrays do have a `.GetEnumerator()` method.</sup>